# How to create a round CheckBox in Flutter ? Or change the CheckBox's style , such as selected image in Flutter?

Tags: checkbox, flutter

I want to create a round CheckBox like this

[image]

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Including I tried to use ClipRRect .

Because there are more code, I only select part of it to show here.

```
new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        //new ClipRRect(
        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
        //  child:
          new Checkbox(
              tristate: true,
              value: true,
              onChanged: (bool newValue){
                setState(() {

                });
              },
            activeColor: Color(0xff06bbfb),
          ),
       // ),

        new Expanded(
            child: new Text('将此手机号码和QQ号绑定，提高账号安全性。',
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff797979)
              ),
            )
        ),

      ],
    ),
```

I am new to Flutter.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can try & play with this Code: **Round CheckBox**

```
 bool _value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Circle CheckBox"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _value = !_value;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: _value
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    size: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )
                : Icon(
                    Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                    size: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is there any other way to keep the original animation of the CheckBox?

Comment: Your example doesn't implement accessibility, and it should not be used in production apps.

Comment: @anmol.majhail what about a CheckboxListTile how do I customize the checkbox here and make it round instead of square?

Answer (score 69):

The Material Design checkbox has a **`shape`** property and you can set **`CircleBorder()`** to it and it will be round.

```
Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
      value: isChecked,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 53):

Since **Flutter 2.2.0**, the **shape** property has been introduced in the [Checkbox Material Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html).

Example for adding round corners to a checkbox:

```
Checkbox(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
)
```

Comment: how about `CheckboxListTile`? it wont change the checkbox shape but the outer lining

Comment: for `CheckboxListTile`, there's a property `checkboxShape`. `checkboxShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))`

Answer (score 14):

Copy the code of the Material Checkbox and create your new Checkbox widget.

In this widget change the variable `const Radius _kEdgeRadius = Radius.circular(1.0)` to `Radius.circular(100)`.

[image]

Comment: If someone need an existed [code](https://github.com/mashnoon33/circular_check_box/blob/master/lib/circular_check_box.dart), just copy It or add It as plugin. I'm not the author, but I found out that It's a bit more work If you copy [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart) directly.

Comment: This should be exposed as a property. Nice solution, anyway.

Answer (score 14):

I had a hard time building this and came up with this solution. I thought someone like me would need it one day. So here it is.

```
ClipRRect(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: Checkbox.width,
        height: Checkbox.width,
        child: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: Checkbox(
              value: isWinnerTakesAll,
              onChanged: (state) =>
                  setState(() => isWinnerTakesAll = !isWinnerTakesAll),
              activeColor: Colors.transparent,
              checkColor: CommonColors.checkBoxColor,
              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

I hope this solves your problem! Any questions are welcomed.

**Reason for using Theme widget**
Without the theme widget, the checkbox had its original square box in the unselected state and I removed it with making it transparent.

Comment: It is nice, but it doesn't have animations. But it is easy to workaround that too, use AnimatedContainer instead of Container, with color and duration. Flutter will make it work nicely

Comment: This solution is worked pretty nice. But adding AnimatedContainer is not giving expected animation. Because checkbox is handling the tap.

Answer (score 10):

**BE AWARE: THIS PACKAGE IS DISCONTINUED !**

There is a simple package you can add that keeps the functionality and animation of the checkbox: https://pub.dev/packages/circular_check_box

Implementation after installing and importing package:

```
CircularCheckBox(
          value: someBooleanValue,
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
          onChanged: (bool x) {
          someBooleanValue = !someBooleanValue;
          }
        ),
```

Comment: Best answer with easiest approach!

Comment: this library is DISCONTINUED and has issue on ios

Answer (score 8):

Set up the Theme like this:

```
 Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: also can use 

checkboxTheme: const CheckboxThemeData(
      shape: StadiumBorder(),
    ),

Answer (score 5):

With **Flutter 2.2.1** shape property is added. so its easy to add change shape of checkbox.

Here I have created a circular checkbox widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircularCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? value;
  final ValueChanged<bool?>? onChanged;
  const CircularCheckbox({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.3,
      child: Checkbox(
        value: value,
        onChanged: onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can scale the checkbox to respect to your design.

for theming the checkbox:
Update themeData of MaterialApp like this:

```
MaterialApp(
theme: ThemeData(toggleableActiveColor: colorScheme.primary,
             checkboxTheme: Theme.of(context).checkboxTheme.copyWith(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              side: BorderSide(
                  width: 1.5, color:
                  Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor),
              splashRadius: 0),)
)
```

by applying the theme you have a nice circular checkbox:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to add a little padding to the checkmark?

Comment: No its not possible. The only solution is use `Checkbox` widget source code and use it for your own custom checkbox with inner padding, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 4):

I had a hard time building this and came up with this solution. I thought someone like me would need it one day. So here it is.

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
        setState(() {
            selected = !selected;
        });
    },
    child: Container(
        height: 28,
        width: 28,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: selected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.green)
        ),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: selected ? Icon(
                Icons.check,
                size: 18.0,
                color: Colors.white,
            ) : Container()
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set the shape of the Checkbox as below;

```dart
Checkbox(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  ),
)
```

[link to documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html)

Comment: Which version has shape property in Checkbox?

Comment: I'm using dev channel, please see `flutter doctor -v` output below


`[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-12.1.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.1.0-12.1.pre at
      /home/.../snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 8264cb3e8a (2 weeks ago), 2021-03-10 12:37:57 -0800
    • Engine revision 711ab3fda0
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-116.0.dev)`

Answer (score 4):

```
Checkbox(
                    value: _bigBox,
//Simply add this line
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    splashRadius: 20,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      _bigBox = value;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
              ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a **CircleBorder**

`Checkbox(shape: CircleBorder())`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircleCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color checkColor;
  final bool tristate;
  final MaterialTapTargetSize materialTapTargetSize;

  CircleCheckbox({
    Key key,
    @required this.value,
    this.tristate = false,
    @required this.onChanged,
    this.activeColor,
    this.checkColor,
    this.materialTapTargetSize,
  })  : assert(tristate != null),
        assert(tristate || value != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipOval(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: Checkbox.width,
        height: Checkbox.width,
        child: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
                width: 2,
                color: Theme.of(context).unselectedWidgetColor ??
                    Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(100),
          ),
          child: Checkbox(
            value: value,
            tristate: tristate,
            onChanged: onChanged,
            activeColor: activeColor,
            checkColor: checkColor,
            materialTapTargetSize: materialTapTargetSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use only material icons to achieve this as below:

```
bool checkboxValue = false;

Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
        GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            setState(() {
            checkboxValue = !checkboxValue;
            });
        },
        child: checkboxValue
            ? Icon(
                Icons.radio_button_checked,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 20,
                )
            : Icon(
                Icons.radio_button_unchecked,
                color: Colors.grey,
                size: 20,
                ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 5),
        Text("Accept Terms and Conditions"),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
      value: isChecked,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2)),
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you complicate it with `ClipRect` ? Just use the official [material icon](https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=check&icon=check_circle&style=baseline).

Comment: Yes, but in fact I am imagining to retain the original animation effect of the CheckBox. Of course, I did not express this meaning before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a boolean variable **acceptTerms**, you can implement it in **Flutter 2.2** like this. Make sure you save your checkbox state too:

```
                Checkbox(
                  value: acceptTerms,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      acceptTerms = !acceptTerms;
                    });
                  },
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**24, May 2023**

```
Checkbox(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        //side: BorderSide(color: green)
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: (checkedValue) ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
              width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5),
            )),
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: Checkbox(
            activeColor: Colors.transparent,
            checkColor: Colors.red,
            value: checkedValue,
            tristate: false,
            onChanged: (bool isChecked) {
              setState(() {
                checkedValue = isChecked;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```